# How to generate point cloud from 3d model

Tags: python, cloud, point

I try to do point cloud semantic segmentation project, unfortunately I haven't dataset. So, I would like to train NN on point clouds, generated from 3d models, and than test it on real data from LIDAR

Answer (score 0):

Solved by sampling point cloud in Blender